# MP3 date tag format

Tags: mp3

I want to tag a whole lot of mp3s (in MediaMonkey) and I was wondering what format I should use for the "date" tag.

Ideas:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
MM/DD/YYYY
MM.DD.YYYY
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Is there any standard for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaMonkey itself automatically converts the dates to the fitting format.
So if you enter

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

It will show

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

in the library (maybe depending on the local settings of your computer) and automatically save the year in ID3V2's "TYER" tag and the date in the "TDAT" tag.

This means it shouldn't matter which format you choose, every player implementing ID3V2 correctly should be able to display it the right way.

Comment: Had to dig in the official ID3V2 documentation. But it's for a good cause! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are used to, I guess. I use DD/MM/YYYY, as I am in the UK, but I have some I got from friends in the US tagged MM/DD/YYYY.

As long as you are consistent in your collection I don't think it matters at all.

Comment: Problem is: It's not for my collection. It's going to be pretty worldwide in the end, I guess.

Comment: I would use YYYY-MM-DD so when you sort alphabetically, they are by date